# Can i add my own project type?

Tags: fabric8

I would like to add a new button here that creates a project with the SBT build system. How do i go about adding a project type in this menu?

Menu image found below

[fabric8 project type picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqzBA.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options really

- create a maven archetype (as in a tarball of stuff you wanna use as the basis of new projects); the tooling will then just work with your archetypes.

Note that the use of maven archetypes is just a way to package sample projects - it doesn't really matter how you build them. e.g. we use maven archetypes to create lots of different projects not using Java ([Swift](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts/swift-example), [Node JS](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts/node-example), [.NET](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts/dotnet-example) etc)

If you have a sample project and don't mind sharing, we could clone it into the [fabric8-quickstarts organisation](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts) & it'll get automatically included in the console in the next release

- create a [JBoss Forge](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-forge) addon. If you wish to create a custom wizard to create new projects using SBT, you can add a new addon to JBoss Forge and we (or you) can then install it into the fabric8-forge docker image

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! Is there anything special I have to do to allow users to pick a custom jenkins-pipeline-script when using the Maven-Archtype project type? Right now When picking a arbitrary maven-architype it shows no pipeline scripts to choose from.

Comment: after clicking "Create App" -> "Create New App" then if you pick the "Quickstart" option that gives you a list of example quickstart archetypes. If you pick one of those, the UI then prompts you to pick a Pipeline (it takes a little while first time you run it - as its downloading some nexus stuff).

Comment: If you select "Maven from Archetype" instead of "Quickstart" - what data did you enter for the maven archetype group / artifact / version? Really the "Quickstart" option is easier to use though

Comment: BTW we should make it easy to add new archetype catalogs on the fly - right now you get a choice of fabric8 + camel - we should be able to make it easy to add them into a ConfigMap or something

Comment: here's an issue describing how we can make it easy to add new archetype catalogs on the fly: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-forge/issues/509